# How to query between two ranges of time

Tags: php, laravel

How do you query between two ranges of `time` without including the two ranges themselves?

I have a working code of querying time using `whereBetween` but I'm having an issue because I only want to get the records *between* those two ranges of time, not including themselves.

I have these rows on my `schedules` table:

```
+----------+------------------+----------------+-------------+
|    id    |    start_time    |    end_time    |   user_id   |
+----------+------------------+----------------+-------------+
|    1     |     06:45:00     |    07:45:00    |      1      |
|    2     |     10:30:00     |    11:30:00    |      1      |
+----------+------------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Steps I'm doing:

1. Add a new record to `schedules` table.
2. Let's say my new record contains `start_time` of **07:45:00**  and `end_time` of **08:45:00**.
3. Check if any record is in between the record to be added, using the code below.

The code I use to check if there is a row that in between the `$startTime` and `$endTime`.

```
$userId = 1;
$startTime = Carbon::parse('07:45')->format('H:i:s');
$endTime = Carbon::parse('08:45')->format('H:i:s');

$checkScheduleIfExists = Schedule::where('user_id', $userId)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($startTime, $endTime) {
        $query->whereBetween('start_time', [
            $startTime, $endTime
        ])
        ->orWhereBetween('end_time', [
            $startTime, $endTime
        ]);
    })
    ->first();

dd($checkScheduleIfExists);

// this returns the row id 1, 06:45:00 - 07:45:00
```

The problem with the code above is it finds the `$startTime` in the `schedules` table's `end_time` which is the **07:45:00** and it returns that row, same goes if it finds the `$endTime` in `start_time`.

What I expect is only to return a row (to know a record exists) if the `$startTime` (07:45:00) occupied lower than the`end_time` that exists in my `schedules` table, for example, **7:40:00**.

Comment: Am I correct in guessing that you don't want the new record to _OVERLAP_ any of the old ones? So, for example, `07:10 - 07:20` should also get row #1 returned, right?

Comment: @Vilx- yes you got it right, because `07:20` is still inside `7:45`

Comment: Right, typing an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty standard problem. And the short answer is: given an interval which starts at `S` and ends at `E`, the DB query to get overlapping intervals should look like:

```
where start<E and end>S
```

##### Explanantion:

To visualize (and better remember) this, imagine two intervals which DON'T overlap. Let's call them `S1-E1` and `S2-E2`.

If they don't overlap, that means that one of them comes first, and the other one comes second. We don't know which one is which, so either `E1 <= S2` (the first one ends before the second one starts) or `E2 <= S1` (the second one ends before the first one starts).

And now that we've written that down, it becomes easy to get all the cases where the two intervals DO overlap in some way - just slap a `not` (negation) in front of this condition. So, in formula-speak: `not(E1 <= S2 or E2 <= S1)`. This condition takes into account every possible way how the intervals could possibly overlap, including one interval completely including the other interval, or intervals overlapping partially.

We can further simplify this expression by opening the parenthesis, in which case we get `E1 > S2 and E2 > S1`.

Comment: aight, let me try this.

Comment: this converts to `whereTime('start_time', '<', $endTime)->whereTime('end_time', '>', $startTime)` ?

Comment: @LuckyPerson yes, I think so. I'm not familiar with Laravel myself, but this looks about right.

Comment: You have a high level of logical thinking, and the edited answer to visualize more, hits me hard to understand, but I'm trying to understand it now.

Comment: @LuckyPerson Naah, I've just used this particular little nugget of information so many times that it's almost instinctive by now, so it's hard to explain. Hmm...

Comment: marking your answer as accepted answer, thank you very much, but still, any answers are welcome if anyone has a translated code based on @Vilx- 's answer.

Comment: @LuckyPerson - Tried to describe it more clearly. Is this better?

Comment: @LuckyPerson TBH when I first learned of this, it took me a while to wrap my brain around it too. And afterwards I still needed to go through the logic steps every time for quite a while, to remember the formula. But after a while I started remembering `just compare the end of one to the start of the other; and slap an AND inbetween`. These days I just need to think a bit about which way the comparisons go (starts need to be less than the ends). And that's how I remember it.

Comment: I really appreciate you - digging to explain this to me, (wow reaction from me). I will save your reply just to read it again some time, and also for reference. Thank you very much!